# A good source for linear algebra on matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, book-recommendation

I am studying for an Algebra qualifying examination to be taken in one month. I need a good source (a book) where I can find the most important theory and examples on linear algebra on matrices. Does anyone know a suitable source for my purpose? Thanks.

Comment: So you need something for abstract algebra with examples from linear algebra, or linear agebra theory, like vector spaces?

Comment: Not abstract algebra, just linear algebra including vector spaces, specially matrices.

Answer (score 2):

One of the best books I've seen on the subject is Gilbert Strang's *Introduction to Linear Algebra*. Here is the [Amazon link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0980232716)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this is the first time you're learning linear algebra, [Paul's notes](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs485/2006sp/LinAlg_Complete.pdf) are a good resource. As for an actual textbook, I recommend [Lay](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321385179) (look for an older edition: they'll be cheaper).

Answer (score 0):

These are lecture notes from Queen Mary university London divided in 2- parts

Linear Algebra 1
http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~raw/MTH5112/ ( in this page i recommend old lecture notes )

Linear Algebra 2 
http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/notes/linalg.pdf

They are very explanatory so you can develop an intuition towards the subject many examples as well.

Comment: QMUL is Queen Mary University of London, not Queen Margaret University (QMU), and the latter is located in Edinburgh, not London.

Comment: @user1551 sorry u r right i will correct